# Serial communication using commConneciton API in j2me

Tags: java-me, serial-port, modbus

I have develop one j2me application for Centrino chip. That chip connected to one EZ power meter. I want to read data from EZ meter over serial communication RS-232 using Modbus protocol.

I have some code for send Modbus request for read Holding Register.

```
 //declare variable here
 CommConnection  commConn;
 InputStream     inStream;
 OutputStream    outStream;
```

// here open com port using commconnection

```
String strCOM = "comm:COM1;baudrate=9600;bitsperchar=8;stopbits=1;parity=even;blocking=on;autocts=off;autorts=off";
commConn = (CommConnection)Connector.open(strCOM);
inStream  = commConn.openInputStream();
outStream = commConn.openOutputStream();
```

// here create modbus protocol request. I want read holding register address 1000 it's hava 2 register.

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

    byte[] frame1 = new byte[] {(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0xE8, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0xBA};
    outStream.write(frame1,0,frame1.length);//write(frame1);
    outStream.flush();
    int available1 = inStream.available();
    System.out.println("inStream Available : "+inStream.available());
    readBytes = inStream.read(buffer,0,available1);

    System.out.println("Read Integer : "+readBytes +" and Bytes size : "+buffer.length);
```

I always got response 0 bytes read. I don't know what is wrong. Please guide me if I write wrong code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at Examples section in http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/CommConnection.html

Comment: Opps! Connection error on chip to meter connection. I had fixd that. After above code if working find. I can read data from Meter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`available()` often returns 0 (for many types of streams) and so it is not very useful. Try just `inStream.read(buffer)`.

Comment: thanks for replay, I test with above change now code freeze on "readBytes = inStream.read(buffer)" line. can you tell why it's happning?

Comment: In general, `read` blocks until input data is available. So either there is no data, or, since you have `blocking=on` in the connection string, there is not enough data to fill the buffer - if that is what is meant by documentation for `blocking` option (_"wait for a full buffer when reading"_). You could try either remove this option, or use `read()` to try to read a single byte. Anyway, neither `read(buffer)` nor `read(buffer,offset,length)` guarantees that it will read `buffer.length` or `length` bytes, so you will need to keep reading until you have enough bytes accrdoing to the protocol.