# Need Modbus Library for j2me

Tags: java-me, serial-port, modbus

I developing one j2me application for read value from power meter over modbus protocol serial communication. I have code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775187/serial-communication-using-commconneciton-api-in-j2me) to read Holding register but m not getting response from meter.so.

Is there any Modbus library for j2me?

Help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A known and mature MODBUS commercial library for Windows and Linux is for example, [SuperCom](http://adontec.com/pmodbus_e.htm). A commercial software library that offers MODBUS for serial and TCP data communications and includes many MODBUS variations too. Client (Master) and Slave functionality also included. And it offers many samples for well known compilers ([more](http://adontec.com/pmodbus_e.htm)).
There surely exist more commercial solutions there.